# Is my nrf24l01 radio module broken?

Tags: nrf24l01+, arduino-nano-every

I was trying to use two Arduino Nano connected to two RF24 modules to build a remote control boat. I self-assembled both the remote and the receiver circuit following the skematic suggested in that page ([NRF24 and Arduino Nano Every usage](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/85341/nrf24-and-arduino-nano-every-usage)).

VCC - 5V (via adapter)

GND - GND

10 pin - CE

A3 - CSN

11 pin - MOSI

12 pin - MISO

13 pin - SCK

not connected - IRQ

(I double and triple checked that I connected all the cables as in the skematic)

Then, as always suggested in the link above, I checked my connection using that sketch:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>

RF24 radio(10,A3);  // for arduino nano every
//RF24 radio(9,10); // for arduino uno

const uint8_t num_channels = 128;
uint8_t values[num_channels];
void setup(void)
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  printf_begin();
  radio.begin();
  radio.setAutoAck(false);
  radio.startListening();

  radio.printDetails();
  delay(5000);

  radio.stopListening();
  int i = 0;
  while ( i < num_channels )  {
    printf("%x",i>>4);
    ++i;
  }
  printf("\n\r");
  i = 0;
  while ( i < num_channels ) {
    printf("%x",i&0xf);
    ++i;
  }
  printf("\n\r");
}
const int num_reps = 100;

void loop(void)
{
  memset(values,0,sizeof(values));
  int rep_counter = num_reps;
  while (rep_counter--) {
    int i = num_channels;
    while (i--) {
      radio.setChannel(i);
      radio.startListening();
      delayMicroseconds(128);
      radio.stopListening();
      if ( radio.testCarrier() )
        ++values[i];
    }
  }
  int i = 0;
  while ( i < num_channels ) {
    printf("%x",min(0xf,values[i]&0xf));
    ++i;
  }
  printf("\n\r");
}
int serial_putc( char c, FILE * ) {
  Serial.write( c );
  return c;
}

void printf_begin(void) {
  fdevopen( &serial_putc, 0 );
}
```

And that's what I found for the RX:

```
STATUS       = 0xff RX_DR=1 TX_DS=1 MAX_RT=1 RX_P_NO=7 TX_FULL=1
RX_ADDR_P0-1     = 0xffffffffff 0xffffffffff
RX_ADDR_P2-5     = 0xff 0xff 0xff 0xff
TX_ADDR      = 0xffffffffff
RX_PW_P0-6   = 0xff 0xff 0xff 0xff 0xff 0xff
EN_AA        = 0xff
EN_RXADDR    = 0xff
RF_CH        = 0xff
RF_SETUP     = 0xff
CONFIG       = 0xff
DYNPD/FEATURE    = 0xff 0xff
Data Rate    = 1MBPS
Model        = nRF24L01
CRC Length   = 16 bits
PA Power     = PA_MAX
00000000000000001111111111111111222222222222222233333333333333334444444444444444555555555555555566666666666666667777777777777777

0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef
```

So that means the RF24 module isn't connected properly to the board, the correct output in the second line would be something like that: RX_ADDR_P0-1 = 0xf0f0f0f0d2 0xc2c2c2c2c2

I used a tester to check the power supply and the antenna receives 3.3V as it should.
I checked also the soldering and I didn't find any poor connections nor short circuits.
I tried all the analog pins between the A0 and A5 for the CSN for perhaps the A3 was not working.

Well, now I ran out of ideas and I'm tempted to think that my radio module is broken, but maybe I overlooked something, can you please write any ideas that you think could help?
Thankyou in advance

Comment: this may help ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=arduino+nrf24l01+hello+world&ia=qa